# why Power int on C is incorrect?

Tags: c, math, pow

Hello guys i was doing my homework basic stuf in C99 but there is something disturbing me please try my code before answer.
The thing is when i try the number 5, 10, 15 the answer is incorrect it's always the correct value - 1.

Can someone explain me why is that please?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int P, x;

    printf("Calculons le polynome P(x)\n");

    printf("Entrer la valeur de x :");

    scanf("%d", &x);

    P = pow(x,2);

    printf("%d", P);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: don't put blank lines between _each_ line.

Comment: `int`-> `double` and `%d` -> `%lf`.

Comment: @MichaelWalz It should work as is.

Comment: cannot reproduce; your code gives me correct results.

Comment: "the answer is incorrect it's always the correct value"  What?

Comment: I would use `x*x` instead of math functions in that case.

Comment: the only thing that could go bad would be if you forgot `math.h`. But you didn't...

Comment: @TavianBarnes: I think the OP meant that it's always the correct value *minus one*.

Comment: I would say the only thing that could go wrong is that the presented code is different from the compiled one. Have you saved your file?

Comment: Using `pow` on integers is generally a bad idea, especially for something simple like squaring an integer. You're converting from `int` to double, passing the converted value to `pow`, and then converting from `double` back to `int`. To square an integer, just multiply it by itself (there's no integer power function in the standard library).

Comment: Try `P = pow(x + 0.0000001, 2);`

Comment: @KeithThompson Oh! That's an interpretation that is making sense.

Comment: Your code works for me. I can imagine that, on some system, for example `pow(5, 2)` might yield something like `24.9999999`, which would truncate to `24` when converted to `int`. What operating system and C implementation are you using?

Comment: Oh, and you should print a newline after your output: `printf("%d\n", P);`

Comment: @KeithThompson I believe it would be correct for any platform conforming to IEEE floating point specs. Maybe it's an embedded system?

Comment: @MarkRansom: There are plenty of poor-quality libm implementations out there, even before looking at embedded systems. Implementing an efficient correctly-rounded pow operation is hard, and I don't know of any common platform that does it.

Comment: It would be interesting to see the output on your system for this program: https://pastebin.com/8yWTvWSP . (And again, what OS and C implementation are you using?) (The OP hasn't been on the system since posting the question, so we'll need to be patient.)

Comment: Hello guys sorry for the late answer.
I'm using Win10 XD and CLion 
I'm saying i have 24 in case of x=5
that's whya i'm saying i have always the correct answer minus one.(bad formulation maybe)

Comment: the result :
`Calculons le polynome P(x)
Entrer la valeur de x :
5
5
24

Process finished with exit code 0`

Comment: You should accept an answer, if it was helpful to you.

Answer (score 2):

The signature of the function *pow* in `math.h` is

```
double pow(double x, double y);
```

Since you pass two integers and assign the result to an integer my guess is that a you get the wrong result due to rounding error and truncation of the decimal part (if you assign 24.999999 to an integer variable you get 24). Also you need to always check the return value from *scanf*. Moreover the output needs to end with a newline, otherwise the result may not show up.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    double P, x;
    int n;

    printf("Calculons le polynome P(x)\n");
    printf("Entrer la valeur de x: ");
    n = scanf("%lf", &x);
    if (n == 1) {
        P = pow(x, 2.0);
        printf("%.2f\n", P);
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Entrée invalide\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This assumes that the problem the OP wants to solve is using `pow` correctly. We can't tell without more feedback, but I suspect the real problem is how to square an integer, and the best solution for that is `x * x`.

Comment: @KeithThompson Indeed! I assume that the poster's code is somewhat simplified to illustrate the problem. However, even for a general polynomial it's probably better to use Horner's method instead of *pow*.

Comment: I see thank you for your explanation, i will check Horner's method
But do you have any explanation why the result is not correct with pow?

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to use x*x, i just simplified the equation, the equation is a bit complicated than x^2, besides i would like to understand why

The thing is if i just put pow(5,2) it works perfectly and i have 25

It's just when i give to x a value like 5 or 10 or 15 that i have the correct value minus one.

i tried to declare P as a double and it works too i have 25.00000
thank you August Karlstrom for your solution, the thing is i'm still wondering why it works if i just put pow(5,2)

here the code using double and it works

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    double P;
    int x;

    printf("Calculons le polynome P(x)\n");    
    printf("Entrer la valeur de x :");    
    scanf("%d", &x);

    P = pow(x,2);

    printf("%f", P);    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please, don't ask questions in a reply, edit you question instead.